# Assigning Django model field within one model to point to one of a choice of other, related models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing an inspection app in Django for a service company and have an esoteric question about my models.  This is the scenario I'm struggling with:

```
Site(models.Model):
    name = CharField()

Generator(models.Model):
    number = CharField()
    site = ForeignKey(Site)

Pump(models.Model):
    number = CharField()
    site = ForeignKey(Site)

Jobs(models.Model):
    asset = ?
    site = ForeignKey(Site)
```

What I would like to do is assign either a Generator OR a Pump object to the asset field in Jobs.  Rather than just generating a list of both generator and pump numbers I would like the field to point to the actual model itself, that way I can backwards reference each job without scanning both tables.

Any ideas?  Would it help to have an asset property in the job model? I am overthinking this?

Using Django 1.11.1 and Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic foreign key as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Since this is a one-line answer. To expand upon that:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Asset(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...

class Job(models.Model):

    assets = GenericRelation(Asset)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it seems to be the way.  But how to relate each Generator and Pump to the asset class you have described above?

Comment: It has this in the documentation. i.e. - You no longer have those. If you wanted to retain distinguishing them (the type of asset) just add a field on which you can filter the type. The power is you can have any number of assets now abstractly defined. In the documentation imaging trying to define a class for every single type of possible tag the case is similar with your assets.

Comment: Thanks again Pythonista.  I still don't fully understand the example in the docs, but now I know where to look - there are lots of posts about generic relations here in SO, so I should be fine.  Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction.